# E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "=": syntax error in getuser Method

Tags: android, sqlite, intellij-idea

the highlighted line causes the problem saying the syntax error please if someone can help

[image: i]

Comment: Copy the required errors and code. Don't post a screen of your desktop and force people to manually copy your code to answer

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide the required whitespace, `AND` operator and quotes:

```
String query = "select email, password from " + table_name + " where " 
                + c_2 + " = '" + mail + "' and " + C_3 + " = '" + pass + "'";
```

Also note that this method is prone to SQL injection. Use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

put spaces near the `where`:

```
+ " where " + ....
```